# When i am uploading video with audio to server the video is running fine in mobile after getting it from api but the video is not running on website

Tags: ios, objective-c

this is my code for merging two video and audio is merged when second video starts

```
AVAsset *firstAsset=[AVAsset assetWithURL:urlIntroVideo];
    AVAsset *secondAsset=[AVAsset assetWithURL:recordedVideoUrl];

    if (firstAsset !=nil && secondAsset!=nil) {
        [[AppDelegate Getdelegate] showIndicator];
        // 1 - Create AVMutableComposition object. This object will hold your AVMutableCompositionTrack instances.
        AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];
        // 2 - Video track

        /********************************************************************************

         --------------->>      VIDEO MERGING TRACK              <<--------------------

         ********************************************************************************/



        AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                            preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

        NSArray *videoTracks = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]];
        NSLog(@"Video Tracks count  1st Assest=> %ld",[videoTracks count]);


        NSArray *audioTracks = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio]];
        NSLog(@"Auido Tracks count => %ld",[audioTracks count]);



        [firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration)
                            ofTrack:[[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

        [firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration)
                            ofTrack:[[secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:firstAsset.duration error:nil];






        //        NSArray *dataSourceArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]];
        //           NSLog(@"array count => %ld",[dataSourceArray count]);
        //        [firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration)
        //                                                                   ofTrack:([dataSourceArray count]>0)?[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:0]:nil
        //                                                                    atTime:kCMTimeZero
        //                                                                     error:nil];
        //
        /********************************************************************************

         --------------->>     AUDIO MERGING TRACK               <<--------------------

         ********************************************************************************/



        AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];


        [audioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration)
                            ofTrack:([audioTracks count]>0)?[audioTracks objectAtIndex:0]:nil
                             atTime:kCMTimeZero
                              error:nil];


        NSArray *audioTracks2 = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio]];
        NSLog(@"Auido Tracks count => %ld",[audioTracks2 count]);

        [audioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration)
                            ofTrack:[[secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0]
                             atTime:firstAsset.duration
                              error:nil];

        //



        //  NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory()
                                        stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
        NSString *myPathDocs = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"final_merged_video-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];


        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];
        // 5 - Create exporter
        AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition
                                                                          presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
        exporter.outputURL=url;
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
        exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
        [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [[AppDelegate Getdelegate] hideIndicator];

                [self exportDidFinish:exporter];
            });
        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Problem is on server side when your WS returns data to server. What your WS developer needs to do is, he need to covert your video with FFMPEG command through terminal. Once he did that, then you can play video on any web site, iOS device & android device.

Comment: thanx for you answer but is it possible to do it in our app rather than on server side

Comment: thanx ..i'll look after it